# How to make a JLabel remain always be on top of another JLabel in Absolute Layout?

Tags: java, netbeans, jlabel, chess

I am building a chess game in java Netbeans, in which pieces are JLabels. So I want the pieces to be always on the top of the square JLabels. But when I change the background colour of the squares to green (to show possible legal moves), the pieces on the square go invisible (or rather they go behind I think). How to make sure the pieces stay above?

**Note : The layout is set to absolute layout.**

Following are the screenshots :

[The actual Board is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stVEL.png)

[You can see the Black queen vanished after mouseOver the Knight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W85W0.png)

and moreover, the knight which was on the light square in the end row, is missing in 1st image and somehow reappears in 2nd. What may be the problem?

Code of Knight class :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chess;

import static chess.Main_interface.labels;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class Knight {
    static void acceptiveSquares(JLabel wn) {
    int index = -1;

        for(int i=0;i<labels.length;i++)
    {
        if(labels[i].getLocation().equals(wn.getLocation()))
            index = i;
    }
           boolean pieceInMiddle = index==18||index==19||index==20||index==21||index==26||index==27||index==28||index==29||index==34||index==35||index==36||index==37||index==42||index==43||index==44||index==45;

        System.out.print(index);
        if(!(index==-1))
        {
            if(pieceInMiddle){
             labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        else if(index==22||index==30||index==38||index==46)
        {
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else if(index==10||index==11||index==12||index==13)
        {
           labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else if(index==50||index==51||index==52||index==53)
        {
           labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==17||index==25||index==33||index==41)
        {
            labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==16||index==24||index==32||index==40)
        {
            labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==23||index==31||index==39||index==47)
        {
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==58||index==59||index==60||index==61)
        {
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==2||index==3||index==4||index==5)
        {
            labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==8)
        {
            labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==15)
        {
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index+15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==48)
        {
            labels[index+10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-15].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
             else if(index==55)
        {
            labels[index+6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-10].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            labels[index-17].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        }
    }
}
```

and the MouseEntered method of knight (and same for other pieces) :

```
 private void wnMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
      Knight.acceptiveSquares(wn);
PieceMovement.Piece=wn;  //setting the movable piece to Knight  
    }
```

Comment: if you are using jlables why do you paint?change background color

Comment: Sorry, see the edit.

Comment: how to you change color to light green?

Comment: By calling a method 'acceptiveSquares(JLabel)' from the Knights class. (same for other pieces having their separate classes).

Comment: probably problem exist in rest of the code.

Comment: @FastSnail, the layout is set to Absolute layout.. Can that be the root of the problem? if yes, how can I solve that?

Comment: You could play with `panel.setComponentZOrder(label, index);`. But you should usually **not** use absolute layout **at all**. Beyond that, you should consider solving your actual problem with a [`JLayeredPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) : Place the "fields" into the lowest layer and the pieces into the highest layer.

Comment: @praveenlondhe it could be .you shouldn't use absolute layout.also in this case i think it's better to draw rectangles and images in a panel by overriding paint component method.if you can post all the codes somewhere alse like pastebin/ghostbin i will test it

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks a heavens for that JLayeredPane hint. Completely solved the problem. Just *void moveToFront(component c)* all the way :D Thanks :D

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a minimal working example. There are dozens line of code that can easily be left out without compromising your question.

Comment: You will probably find it easier to just handle all the board drawing yourself onto a simple canvas rather than trying to use the Swing components for things they weren't really designed to do.